# Insert new colum in DataFrame with diff from previous row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a dataset, which is looking like this:

```
                           floor_temperature  power_consumption  outside_temperature
timestamp
2019-01-23 00:00:00+00:00           8.300000           0.022000           -11.393333
2019-01-23 00:10:00+00:00           8.114286           0.016000           -11.400000
2019-01-23 00:20:00+00:00           7.950000           0.044000           -11.254545
2019-01-23 00:30:00+00:00           7.900000           0.027500           -11.300000
2019-01-23 00:40:00+00:00           7.840000         830.900000           -11.400000
2019-01-23 00:50:00+00:00           8.300000         334.352000           -11.400000
2019-01-23 01:00:00+00:00           8.580000           0.028000           -11.380000
2019-01-23 01:10:00+00:00           8.440000           0.018000           -11.400000
2019-01-23 01:20:00+00:00           8.360000           0.022000           -11.400000
```

I would like to insert a new row after "floor_temperatur", which should be named "diff_floor_ temperature" and it should be calculated by taking the rows "floor_temperature" minus the previous rows "floor_temperature".

I know it should be quite easy with the .diff() function, but it would be nice with some help on the syntax.

Comment: Whats wrong witb the syntax you tried? Is there an error?

Comment: `df['diff_floor_temperature'] = df['floor_temperature'].diff()`?

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving 0x5453's answer to the answer column but changing a couple of things to make sure that you don't get any slicing errors.

`df.loc[:,'diff_floor_temperature'] = df.loc[:,'floor_temperature'].diff()`

Comment: Could you explain the issue with potential slicing errors?

Comment: If you're trying to make calculations on slices you could get the following warning, the documentation does a good job explaining why you should start using .loc instead of just normal brackets

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy